# Terminology: Press and Hold -or- Hold?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, terminology

"Press and hold" (or touch and hold) is clearly the full description.
However, is "hold" alone clear enough for users?

> Instruction: Press and hold the button for 3 seconds.

> Instruction: Hold the button for 3 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it ultimately depends on the context and the specific element being referred to, in my opinion, using **"Hold"** alone may not be sufficient to provide clear instructions. Although it may be understandable to the majority of users, there is a chance that a small percentage could become confused or unsure of what action to take. To err on the side of caution, unless there are constraints with space or other considerations, I would recommend using the full instruction **"Press and hold"** (or **"Touch and hold"** if you want) to ensure clarity for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions should be clear on what action a customer is exactly supported to take.

For desktop: Click and Hold or Press and Hold the  for 3 seconds

For mobile users: Tap and Hold the  for 3 seconds